# ddev using drush behind proxy fails to connect

Tags: proxy, drush, ddev

running ddev excec drush up module -y fails behind a proxy.
so I went in the container with ddev ssh and **added the proxy to a .wgetrc** file inside the users home dir.

I am running ddev in win10 and linux (didn't drush up in linux yet) behind a company proxy.

Why is setting a proxy is necessary at all aren't the containers nated? Is there an alternative way to set a proxy for the container?

My output of netstat looks like this:

```
Proto  Lokale Adresse         Remoteadresse          Status
  TCP    10.0.75.1:445          10.0.75.2:41614        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:49271     10.12.32.12:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:49339     10.12.32.12:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:49359     10.12.0.22:443         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:49369     10.12.32.22:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:49372     10.12.32.22:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:49374     10.12.32.22:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:49375     10.12.32.22:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:49376     10.7.17.12:445         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:56920     10.13.1.54:10123       HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:56949     10.12.3.12:445         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:56951     10.12.11.41:445        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:56993     10.12.11.43:445        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:57229     10.12.32.12:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:58195     10.12.32.12:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:59098     10.90.228.13:22        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:63018     10.12.32.12:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    10.90.228.92:65074     10.12.32.22:80         HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49691        127.0.0.1:49692        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49692        127.0.0.1:49691        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:56995        127.0.0.1:56996        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:56996        127.0.0.1:56995        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57020        127.0.0.1:57021        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57021        127.0.0.1:57020        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57022        127.0.0.1:57023        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57023        127.0.0.1:57022        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57024        127.0.0.1:57025        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57025        127.0.0.1:57024        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57034        127.0.0.1:62522        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57039        127.0.0.1:57040        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57040        127.0.0.1:57039        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57223        127.0.0.1:57224        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57224        127.0.0.1:57223        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57225        127.0.0.1:57226        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57226        127.0.0.1:57225        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57232        127.0.0.1:57233        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57233        127.0.0.1:57232        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57284        127.0.0.1:57285        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57285        127.0.0.1:57284        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57339        127.0.0.1:57340        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57340        127.0.0.1:57339        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:62522        127.0.0.1:57034        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63180        127.0.0.1:63181        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63181        127.0.0.1:63180        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63182        127.0.0.1:63183        HERGESTELLT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:63183        127.0.0.1:63182        HERGESTELLT
```

Comment: Per this it does look like drush uses wget... https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193654/how-to-use-drush-with-proxy) - Your first step is to get wget working inside the web container, when that happens, I think you'll be able to get the rest of the way. Note that you'll end up having to mount or otherwise add the .wgetrc in your config.yaml or docker-compose.wget.yaml or something, because it will be lost on every `ddev start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a docker-compose.wget.yaml inside the .ddev directory with the following content and adding a .wgetrc file fixed the internet access for drush:

docker-compose.wget.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - ".wgetrc:/home/.wgetrc"
```

.wgetrc

```
use_proxy = on
https_proxy = http://<yourproxy>:80
http_proxy = http://<yourproxy>:80
```

Thanks to [rfay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215713/rfay) for the hint and the great work!